# CURTIME() SQL Issues

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have tried multiple ways of formatting/retrieving just the `TIME` portion of a `DATETIME` function without success. Everything I have read online says `CURTIME()` will return the current time. It does, but returns the date as well. I have no interest in the date, as the field I am filling is a time only field. Granted the field type is `DATETIME`.

When I run my code, I view my table through Access 2007. I see the date as well as the `TIME` portion. When I do the `CURDATE()` function for my Date field it shows just the `DATE` just fine.

I have extensively googled this issue of having the `DATE` portion appear, but every single seemingly 'fix' to the issue is the same thing over and over, ie. Casting/converting (`CONVERT` doesn't seem to be a function in the current MySQL ODBC version I am using). When attempting to be simple and `UPDATE` the time with a string, simply nothing shows up in the Field when I refresh the Access tables.

Anyone have any ideas? Google has failed me.

Comment: I have tried CAST(NOW() AS TIME)
TIME(NOW()),
as well as all the above with CURTIME() function.
The field of type DateTime in Access displays 1/28/2015 11:07:25 AM or what ever the current system time is. EVerything I have tried seems to not disregard the DATE portion of the function.

Comment: No body has any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried changing the fieldtype from datetime to time?

Comment: I am attempting to reverse engineer from a program, and access wont let me actually manipulate field types, and therefore stuck as DateTime. WHen the program produces these tables, the time entry is only the Time stamp.. which is exactly what I want, but can't seem to reproduce. WIth that being said, the database I am using does not even contain a strictly TIME only field type. only Date/Time

Comment: If reading from a DB try `SELECT RIGHT(DateTimeField,8) FROM tableName`. If you are trying to write to a DateTime field, I fear you will need to include a date, maybe try `CONCAT('0000-00-00 ',CURTIME())`  and then write a function to just pick the time part when you read it back later?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... For what ever reason the only spot for formatting that would be accepted was in the format field in the Design View from the Access 2007 view of the tables. hh:mm:ss AM/PM was necessary in the format field, apparently this is the only way to format a CURTIME() or any DATETIME function from a C# into the SQL/database I was using at least.